# android R.integer returns incorrect Extremely large value causing out of mem while creating array

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-resources, largenumber

I have declared few integer values in an xml and need to use the values in a Class to define the array size of an object.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--     Default Object Count -->
    <item format="integer" name="item1" type="integer">3</item>
    <item format="integer" name="item2" type="integer">1</item>
    <item format="integer" name="item3" type="integer">1</item>
</resources>
```

I am using above values in my class as follows

```java
public class InitialiseObjects {
    // For now static number of objects initialized
    private String TAG = "INIT_OBJECTS";
    int ITEM1_COUNT = R.integer.item1;
    int ITEM2_COUNT = R.integer.item2;
    int ITEM3_COUNT = R.integer.item3;

    private Item1[] item1Objs = new Item1[ITEM1_COUNT];
    private Item2[] item2Objs = new Item2[ITEM2_COUNT];
    private Item3[] item3Objs = new Item3[ITEM3_COUNT];
}
```

I expect ITEM*_COUNT to be 3,1,1 respectively for items 1,2,3.
However I get 2131034112, 2131034113, 2131034114 respectively

What's wrong here ?

Android 2.2 [API-8] is being used

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`R.integer.item1` is the ID of the resource, and thus a very big and arbitrary integer.

The value your looking for is  `getContext().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.item1);`

Thus, you won't be able to get them in a static code.

You should use lazy initialization in your code :

```
private Item1[] item1Objs;
public Item1[] getItem1Array(Context context) {
  if (item1Objs == null) {
     int count = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.item1);
     item1Objs = new Item1[count];
     }
  return item1Objs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/1620937/orabig , I couldn't see any specific mention about `R.integer.<id>` returning an ID integer in documentation. Also had been loading bitmaps `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.myimage)` and thought `R.<type>.<id>` returns the associated object

Answer (score 2):

Do like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
int maxSpeed = res.getInteger(R.integer.max_speed);
```

See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that any R.integer.* is a generated integer value, it's like an id which is related to your value declared in xml

You should rather call

```
getResources().getInteger(R.integer.*);
```